# WPF DataTemplate ContentPresenter "Binding"

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Can someone explain me how the code I am using here can work?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:PBRKEntryViewModel}">
        <V:Overview  />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:LoginViewModel}">
        <V:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Grid>
```

My current problems in Details are:

- Why can the ContentPresenter present the correct UserControl without Reference to the different DataTemplates? I can see, that ContentPresenter content is bound to my ViewModels CurrentViewProperty but my DataTemplates not?
- Another great feature is that the UserControls using the correct ViewModels without a declaration. (Or without a declaration I can see)

I have found this description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter(v=vs.110).aspx but the remarks section has no answer to this questions. (Or I couldn´t see them...)

Again and just for clarity everything is working perfect, but I do not understand why, so this is just a question to understand the Selection of the template and the Binding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DateTemplates that specify a [DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Styling_DataType) property are automatically applied to any instance of that type in the view. It's just a way to tell WPF "every time you need to display this type, use this template"

Your `ContentPresenter` has its `Content` bound to some object. If that object type has a matching template, then WPF will use it.

Answer (score 6):

Under the remarks section of the link you posted it's clear enough with this statement:

> If there is a DataTemplate associated with the type of Content, the
>   ContentPresenter applies that DataTemplate to the Content property and
>   the resulting UIElement and its child elements, if any, are displayed.

Also, if you want to know how dataTemplates are picked automatically, you can read about it here - [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Quote from the link:

> The DataTemplate class has a DataType property that is very similar to
>   the TargetType property of the Style class. DataTemplate gets applied
>   automatically to all objects associated with underlying type.

This is something **similar to Styles**. If you doesn't specify any `x:Key` on your Style it will be applied automatically to all child elements falling under the root element where resource is defined.

As soon as you set `x:Key` on Style, it is no more a default style and will be applied only to the elements explicitly setting style to this resource.

Same holds true for `DataTemplate` as well. When you specify `DataType` only, it becomes default template to represent underlying data type. Explicitly specifying `x:Key` will break this feature.

Comment: Thank you to, i have read through the MSDN Remarks article again, and your right the Statement is clear now.