# How to bind DataTemplates to ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatemplate

I have read some questions-answers explaining this topic ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996682/wpf-mvvm-load-a-view-dynamically-at-runtime),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504291/wpf-datatemplate-contentpresenter-binding),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940369/change-contentpresenters-datatemplate)) but i'm still missing something.

I have defined a `ResourceDictionary` with several `DataTemplate` for exmaple :

```
 <ResourceDictionary
        xmlns:wvm="clr-namespace:Octopus.Widgets.ViewModels;assembly=Octopus.Widgets"
        xmlns:wuc="clr-namespace:Octopus.Widgets.Controls;assembly=Octopus.Widgets">
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wvm:ClockViewModel}">
        <wuc:Clock />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And merge it in the `Application.Resources` `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` section.
Now comes the part i don't understand.
How do I show a template in other control? I saw the use of `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>` but can't really understand it. Does the ViewModel of the container(parent) has a CurrentView property ? and what type it is then? 
this is the parent-container control-view :

```
<Grid>
<!-- hard coded control - i want to change it -->
<Button>
    <wuc:Clock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
        <wuc:Clock.DataContext>
            <wvm:ClockViewModel/>
        </wuc:Clock.DataContext>
    </wuc:Clock>
</Button>

<!-- another try -->
<!--<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{Binding WidgetTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>-->
</Grid>
```

Thanks
EDIT 
My goal is to be able to switch widget based on key comming from DB.
Container control has a ViewModel with some properties not related to question. But maybe missing one that does and this is my question.

Comment: please clearly describe which data (viewmodels) you have and which behavior(scenarios, use-cases) you want to achive with them.

Comment: You may just want to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). It clearly explains how a DataTemplate is automatically chosen by its DataType. You would of course not explicitly assign a Clock to the Content of a Button, but a ClockViewModel instead. The Clock would then be created by the automatically applied DataTemplate.

Comment: "switch widget based on key comming from DB" - ok, I can think of half a dozen ways. One of them will probably work for you.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Sometimes what might seen clear to one is chaos to another.

Answer (score 1):

For the generations to come here is my solution:(thanks to @clemens for putting me on track)

In the container ViewModel i added a property to hold the selected widget type

```
public object Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            content = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }
```

and according to Widget i needed i initialized a new ViewModel (defined in DataTemplate) 
And the xaml i used :

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
```

Simple enough....